# Is it possible to localize title tip values for sort options in Ag Grid?

Tags: ag-grid-react

Not able to localize title tip values show in below image. Can any has done this before? Please post a example.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLp9M.png)

Thanks in Advance.
-Sravan

Tried as mention below. but sort option are not translated.
https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/a799e52ac096515fb1332ca7619acf43f2090c6f/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/documentation/doc-pages/localisation/examples/localisation/locale.zzz.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

*Steps*

1. Generate a new file called locale.en.js and copy paste the content below

```
// Example locale file for English, give this to your locale team to translate

const AG_GRID_LOCALE_EN = {
  // Set Filter
  selectAll: '(Select All)',
  selectAllSearchResults: '(Select All Search Results)',
  searchOoo: 'Search...',
  blanks: '(Blanks)',
  noMatches: 'No matches',

  // Number Filter & Text Filter
  filterOoo: 'Filter...',
  equals: 'Equals',
  notEqual: 'Not equal',
  blank: 'Blank',
  notBlank: 'Not blank',
  empty: 'Choose One',

  // Number Filter
  lessThan: 'Less than',
  greaterThan: 'Greater than',
  lessThanOrEqual: 'Less than or equal',
  greaterThanOrEqual: 'Greater than or equal',
  inRange: 'In range',
  inRangeStart: 'from',
  inRangeEnd: 'to',

  // Text Filter
  contains: 'Contains',
  notContains: 'Not contains',
  startsWith: 'Starts with',
  endsWith: 'Ends with',

  // Date Filter
  dateFormatOoo: 'yyyy-mm-dd',

  // Filter Conditions
  andCondition: 'AND',
  orCondition: 'OR',

  // Filter Buttons
  applyFilter: 'Apply',
  resetFilter: 'Reset',
  clearFilter: 'Clear',
  cancelFilter: 'Cancel',

  // Filter Titles
  textFilter: 'Text Filter',
  numberFilter: 'Number Filter',
  dateFilter: 'Date Filter',
  setFilter: 'Set Filter',

  // Group Column Filter
  groupFilterSelect: 'Select field:',

  // Side Bar
  columns: 'Columns',
  filters: 'Filters',

  // columns tool panel
  pivotMode: 'Pivot Mode',
  groups: 'Row Groups',
  rowGroupColumnsEmptyMessage: 'Drag here to set row groups',
  values: 'Values',
  valueColumnsEmptyMessage: 'Drag here to aggregate',
  pivots: 'Column Labels',
  pivotColumnsEmptyMessage: 'Drag here to set column labels',

  // Header of the Default Group Column
  group: 'Group',

  // Row Drag
  rowDragRow: 'row',
  rowDragRows: 'rows',

  // Other
  loadingOoo: 'Loading...',
  loadingError: 'ERR',
  noRowsToShow: 'No Rows To Show',
  enabled: 'Enabled',

  // Menu
  pinColumn: 'Pin Column',
  pinLeft: 'Pin Left',
  pinRight: 'Pin Right',
  noPin: 'No Pin',
  valueAggregation: 'Value Aggregation',
  noAggregation: 'None',
  autosizeThiscolumn: 'Autosize This Column',
  autosizeAllColumns: 'Autosize All Columns',
  groupBy: 'Group by',
  ungroupBy: 'Un-Group by',
  addToValues: 'Add ${variable} to values',
  removeFromValues: 'Remove ${variable} from values',
  addToLabels: 'Add ${variable} to labels',
  removeFromLabels: 'Remove ${variable} from labels',
  resetColumns: 'Reset Columns',
  expandAll: 'Expand All Row Groups',
  collapseAll: 'Close All Row Groups',
  copy: 'Copy',
  ctrlC: 'Ctrl+C',
  ctrlX: 'Ctrl+X',
  copyWithHeaders: 'Copy With Headers',
  copyWithGroupHeaders: 'Copy with Group Headers',
  cut: 'Cut',
  paste: 'Paste',
  ctrlV: 'Ctrl+V',
  export: 'Export',
  csvExport: 'CSV Export',
  excelExport: 'Excel Export',

  // Enterprise Menu Aggregation and Status Bar
  sum: 'Sum',
  first: 'First',
  last: 'Last',
  min: 'Min',
  max: 'Max',
  none: 'None',
  count: 'Count',
  avg: 'Average',
  filteredRows: 'Filtered',
  selectedRows: 'Selected',
  totalRows: 'Total Rows',
  totalAndFilteredRows: 'Rows',
  more: 'More',
  to: 'to',
  of: 'of',
  page: 'Page',
  pageLastRowUnknown: '?',
  nextPage: 'Next Page',
  lastPage: 'Last Page',
  firstPage: 'First Page',
  previousPage: 'Previous Page',

  // Pivoting
  pivotColumnGroupTotals: 'Total',

  // Enterprise Menu (Charts)
  pivotChartAndPivotMode: 'Pivot Chart & Pivot Mode',
  pivotChart: 'Pivot Chart',
  chartRange: 'Chart Range',

  columnChart: 'Column',
  groupedColumn: 'Grouped',
  stackedColumn: 'Stacked',
  normalizedColumn: '100% Stacked',

  barChart: 'Bar',
  groupedBar: 'Grouped',
  stackedBar: 'Stacked',
  normalizedBar: '100% Stacked',

  pieChart: 'Pie',
  pie: 'Pie',
  doughnut: 'Doughnut',

  line: 'Line',

  xyChart: 'X Y (Scatter)',
  scatter: 'Scatter',
  bubble: 'Bubble',

  areaChart: 'Area',
  area: 'Area',
  stackedArea: 'Stacked',
  normalizedArea: '100% Stacked',

  histogramChart: 'Histogram',
  histogramFrequency: 'Frequency',

  combinationChart: 'Combination',
  columnLineCombo: 'Column & Line',
  AreaColumnCombo: 'Area & Column',

  // Charts
  pivotChartTitle: 'Pivot Chart',
  rangeChartTitle: 'Range Chart',
  settings: 'Settings',
  data: 'Data',
  format: 'Format',
  categories: 'Categories',
  defaultCategory: '(None)',
  series: 'Series',
  xyValues: 'X Y Values',
  paired: 'Paired Mode',
  axis: 'Axis',
  navigator: 'Navigator',
  color: 'Color',
  thickness: 'Thickness',
  xType: 'X Type',
  automatic: 'Automatic',
  category: 'Category',
  number: 'Number',
  time: 'Time',
  autoRotate: 'Auto Rotate',
  xRotation: 'X Rotation',
  yRotation: 'Y Rotation',
  ticks: 'Ticks',
  width: 'Width',
  height: 'Height',
  length: 'Length',
  padding: 'Padding',
  spacing: 'Spacing',
  chart: 'Chart',
  title: 'Title',
  titlePlaceholder: 'Chart title - double click to edit',
  background: 'Background',
  font: 'Font',
  top: 'Top',
  right: 'Right',
  bottom: 'Bottom',
  left: 'Left',
  labels: 'Labels',
  size: 'Size',
  minSize: 'Minimum Size',
  maxSize: 'Maximum Size',
  legend: 'Legend',
  position: 'Position',
  markerSize: 'Marker Size',
  markerStroke: 'Marker Stroke',
  markerPadding: 'Marker Padding',
  itemSpacing: 'Item Spacing',
  itemPaddingX: 'Item Padding X',
  itemPaddingY: 'Item Padding Y',
  layoutHorizontalSpacing: 'Horizontal Spacing',
  layoutVerticalSpacing: 'Vertical Spacing',
  strokeWidth: 'Stroke Width',
  lineDash: 'Line Dash',
  offset: 'Offset',
  offsets: 'Offsets',
  tooltips: 'Tooltips',
  callout: 'Callout',
  markers: 'Markers',
  shadow: 'Shadow',
  blur: 'Blur',
  xOffset: 'X Offset',
  yOffset: 'Y Offset',
  lineWidth: 'Line Width',
  normal: 'Normal',
  bold: 'Bold',
  italic: 'Italic',
  boldItalic: 'Bold Italic',
  predefined: 'Predefined',
  fillOpacity: 'Fill Opacity',
  strokeOpacity: 'Line Opacity',
  histogramBinCount: 'Bin count',
  columnGroup: 'Column',
  barGroup: 'Bar',
  pieGroup: 'Pie',
  lineGroup: 'Line',
  scatterGroup: 'X Y (Scatter)',
  areaGroup: 'Area',
  histogramGroup: 'Histogram',
  combinationGroup: 'Combination',
  groupedColumnTooltip: 'Grouped',
  stackedColumnTooltip: 'Stacked',
  normalizedColumnTooltip: '100% Stacked',
  groupedBarTooltip: 'Grouped',
  stackedBarTooltip: 'Stacked',
  normalizedBarTooltip: '100% Stacked',
  pieTooltip: 'Pie',
  doughnutTooltip: 'Doughnut',
  lineTooltip: 'Line',
  groupedAreaTooltip: 'Area',
  stackedAreaTooltip: 'Stacked',
  normalizedAreaTooltip: '100% Stacked',
  scatterTooltip: 'Scatter',
  bubbleTooltip: 'Bubble',
  histogramTooltip: 'Histogram',
  columnLineComboTooltip: 'Column & Line',
  areaColumnComboTooltip: 'Area & Column',
  customComboTooltip: 'Custom Combination',
  noDataToChart: 'No data available to be charted.',
  pivotChartRequiresPivotMode: 'Pivot Chart requires Pivot Mode enabled.',
  chartSettingsToolbarTooltip: 'Menu',
  chartLinkToolbarTooltip: 'Linked to Grid',
  chartUnlinkToolbarTooltip: 'Unlinked from Grid',
  chartDownloadToolbarTooltip: 'Download Chart',
  seriesChartType: 'Series Chart Type',
  seriesType: 'Series Type',
  secondaryAxis: 'Secondary Axis',

  // ARIA
  ariaChecked: 'checked',
  ariaColumn: 'Column',
  ariaColumnGroup: 'Column Group',
  ariaColumnList: 'Column List',
  ariaColumnSelectAll: 'Toggle Select All Columns',
  ariaDateFilterInput: 'Date Filter Input',
  ariaDefaultListName: 'List',
  ariaFilterColumnsInput: 'Filter Columns Input',
  ariaFilterFromValue: 'Filter from value',
  ariaFilterInput: 'Filter Input',
  ariaFilterList: 'Filter List',
  ariaFilterToValue: 'Filter to value',
  ariaFilterValue: 'Filter Value',
  ariaFilterMenuOpen: 'Open Filter Menu',
  ariaFilteringOperator: 'Filtering Operator',
  ariaHidden: 'hidden',
  ariaIndeterminate: 'indeterminate',
  ariaInputEditor: 'Input Editor',
  ariaMenuColumn: 'Press CTRL ENTER to open column menu.',
  ariaRowDeselect: 'Press SPACE to deselect this row',
  ariaRowSelectAll: 'Press Space to toggle all rows selection',
  ariaRowToggleSelection: 'Press Space to toggle row selection',
  ariaRowSelect: 'Press SPACE to select this row',
  ariaSearch: 'Search',
  ariaSortableColumn: 'Press ENTER to sort',
  ariaToggleVisibility: 'Press SPACE to toggle visibility',
  ariaToggleCellValue: 'Press SPACE to toggle cell value',
  ariaUnchecked: 'unchecked',
  ariaVisible: 'visible',
  ariaSearchFilterValues: 'Search filter values',

  // ARIA Labels for Drop Zones

  ariaRowGroupDropZonePanelLabel: 'Row Groups',
  ariaValuesDropZonePanelLabel: 'Values',
  ariaPivotDropZonePanelLabel: 'Column Labels',
  ariaDropZoneColumnComponentDescription: 'Press DELETE to remove',
  ariaDropZoneColumnValueItemDescription:
    'Press ENTER to change the aggregation type',
  ariaDropZoneColumnGroupItemDescription: 'Press ENTER to sort',
  // used for aggregate drop zone, format: {aggregation}{ariaDropZoneColumnComponentAggFuncSeparator}{column name}
  ariaDropZoneColumnComponentAggFuncSeparator: ' of ',
  ariaDropZoneColumnComponentSortAscending: 'ascending',
  ariaDropZoneColumnComponentSortDescending: 'descending',

  // ARIA Labels for Dialogs
  ariaLabelColumnMenu: 'Column Menu',
  ariaLabelCellEditor: 'Cell Editor',
  ariaLabelDialog: 'Dialog',
  ariaLabelSelectField: 'Select Field',
  ariaLabelTooltip: 'Tooltip',
  ariaLabelContextMenu: 'Context Menu',
  ariaLabelSubMenu: 'SubMenu',
  ariaLabelAggregationFunction: 'Aggregation Function',

  // Number Format (Status Bar, Pagination Panel)
  thousandSeparator: ',',
  decimalSeparator: '.',

  // Data types
  true: 'True',
  false: 'False',
  invalidDate: 'Invalid Date',
  invalidNumber: 'Invalid Number',
  january: 'January',
  february: 'February',
  march: 'March',
  april: 'April',
  may: 'May',
  june: 'June',
  july: 'July',
  august: 'August',
  september: 'September',
  october: 'October',
  november: 'November',
  december: 'December',
};
```

2. Generate another file called locale.de.js and copy paste the content below

```
var AG_GRID_LOCALE_DE = {};

// Here we prefix english words with 'GERMAN' string
Object.keys(AG_GRID_LOCALE_EN).forEach(function (key) {
  if (key === 'thousandSeparator' || key === 'decimalSeparator') {
    return;
  }
  AG_GRID_LOCALE_DE[key] = 'GERMAN-' + AG_GRID_LOCALE_EN[key];
});
```

3. In index.html file, put reference

```
<body>
  <script src="locale.en.js">
  </script>
  <script src="locale.de.js">
  </script>
</body>
```

4. Inside the main app, use it as locale

```
  const localeText = useMemo(() => {
    return AG_GRID_LOCALE_DE;
  }, []);

  return (
        <AgGridReact
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          localeText={localeText}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
  )
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/RHu7AfbCXCWEXpjZ